# Service does not work when the screen is turned off

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to make a timer that notifies the user after a short amount of time (seconds up to a few minutes). The user should be able to track the remaining time via a notification.

This works fine until the screen is turned off and the device is disconnected from the power supply. Depending on the device, the notification will stop updating after a few seconds up to 30 seconds with turned-off screen. After unlocking the device, the timer continues.

I tested it with a device that uses API level 24 and one with API level 28.

My approach is to use a foreground service and wake lock. I created a new project to isolate the problem:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace Background_Timer_Test.Droid
{
    [Service]
    public class TimerService : Service
    {
        const string CHANNEL_ID = "test_channel";
        const int NOTIFICATION_ID = 4321;

        private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
        private Timer mTimer = new Timer();
        private DateTime mStartTime;
        private NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder;
        private NotificationManagerCompat mNotificationManagerCompat;

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            throw null;
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            PowerManager pmanager = (PowerManager)GetSystemService("power");
            mWakeLock = pmanager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, PackageName);
            mWakeLock.Acquire();
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

            CreateNotification();

            mStartTime = DateTime.Now;

            mTimer.Interval = 1000;
            mTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) => UpdateNotificationText(((int)(DateTime.Now - mStartTime).TotalSeconds).ToString());
            mTimer.Start();

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            if (mWakeLock != null)
            {
                mWakeLock.Release();
                mWakeLock = null;
            }

            StopForeground(true);

            base.OnDestroy();
        }

        private void CreateNotification()
        {
            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            mNotificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "test_channel_name", NotificationImportance.High)
                {
                    Description = "A test channel"
                };

                notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .SetSmallIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.StatNotifySync)
            .SetOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .SetContentTitle("Background Timer")
            .SetContentText("Text");

            StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotificationBuilder.Build());
        }

        private void UpdateNotificationText(string text)
        {
            mNotificationBuilder.SetContentText(text);
            mNotificationManagerCompat.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotificationBuilder.Build());
        }
    }
}
```

In `MainActivity.OnCreate` I added:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(TimerService));
if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
{
    StartForegroundService(intent);
}
else
{
    StartService(intent);
}
```

I added the permissions `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` and `WAKE_LOCK`.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Start Foreground service should be okay. But the problem arises with the fact that there is a huge number of devices that block even foreground services. I would check the code with my device and give the feedback.

Comment: The device which Android version is higher than Oreo is a Huawei Mate 9 and the one with the lower version is a Honor 8.
I installed a couple of interval timer apps on both devices and some of them do not have this issue. They even play sounds and do vibration while the screen is turned off. The working apps use the same power-related permissions as in my code, only one uses receive_boot_completed in addition.

Comment: I think it related to the specific version device. For now, no more ways for these specific devices to fix it.